# how to reference an angular value so that reference does not get destroyed on minification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify

The following code is working fine before minifiaction. Essentially, editableOptions is an angular value provided by the angular-xeditable library.

```
angular.module('common').run(function(editableOptions) {
        editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
    }
)
```

However, when I minify, I get an injection error. I believe this is because `editableOptions` is getting minfied. How can I reference it differently so that this does not occur? Is there some way of referencing it starting with `angular.module('xeditable')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the minification-safe method of defining injected objects:

```
angular.module('common').run(
   ['editableOptions', 
      function(editableOptions) {
          editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
      }
   ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular team have a solution to this problem mentioned in one of their tutorials:

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05

> **A Note on Minification**
>
> Since Angular infers the controller's dependencies from the names of arguments to the controller's constructor function, if you were to minify the JavaScript code for PhoneListCtrl controller, all of its function arguments would be minified as well, and the dependency injector would not be able to identify services correctly.
>
> We can overcome this problem by annotating the function with the names of the dependencies, provided as strings, which will not get minified.

Answer (score 0):

This is another style to avoid minification and uglification problems:

```
function runModule(editableOptions) {
  editableOptions.theme = 'bs3';
}

runModule.$inject = ['editableOptions'];

angular.module('common').run(runModule);
```

> [Todd Motto Angular Style
>   Guide](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide#angularjs-styleguide)
>
> This aids with readability and reduces the volume of code "wrapped"
>   inside the Angular framework